# Unable to run selenium with python using unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

Using below Configuration :

> macOS Sierra 10.12.4, Python version 2.7, Selenium version 3.5

I'm trying to write a script in Pycharm with selenium webdriver and unittest modules. My goal is to go to a site find the element(button) and click on the button. I tried using Firefox driver and Chrome driver. I also tried to run this without the IDE but no luck. I been searching all over but can't get to work.

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class HomeWorkTeam(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/<user>/HomeWork/chromedriver')


    def test_team_search(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org/index.html")
        teamelem = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
        teamelem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        assert "No results found" not in driver.page_source


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

When I run this this is the output but the browsers does not get launched.

> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

I assume you ran it using below

```
python -m unittest
```

If your file with this test is `myunit` then you need to use below to run it

```
$ python -m unittest -v myunit

test_team_search (myunit.HomeWorkTeam) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 6.455s

OK
```

PS: Refer to https://docs.python.org/devguide/runtests.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

Add `@classmethod` for the `setUp` and `teardown` methods. Also, remove indentation for if statement. indentation is same as class method.

```py
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.close()
    cls.driver.quit()
    print('Test completed')
```